# Do eigenvectors include complex vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working on restoring my linear algebra knowledge from a few years ago by walking through a few simple examples to rebuild my intuitions, and I stumbled on an interesting problem.

I was trying to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$ and it seems that the constraints defining the eigenvectors allow for any vector in the span composed of two lines:

$$\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
n \\
2n
\end{bmatrix} \forall \ n$$
$$\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
n \\
-n
\end{bmatrix} \forall \ n$$

But this presents an interesting question: *For all n in what number space?*

When tasked with finding the eigenvectors of a matrix, would there be some implicit assumption we're talking about the reals ($\mathbb{R}$), indicating an eigenvector along a line in 2-dimensional space, or could we be talking about the complex number space ($\mathbb{C}$), indicating a plane in 3-dimensional space?

Comment: The "number space" (not a technical term) in which $n$ lives is [whichever field the vector space is over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition). (The space in which the matrix lives is over the same field.)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Linear Algebra, the eigenspaces must be vector spaces. So, $\mathbb N$ cannot possibly be an option here.

Is it $\mathbb R$ or is it $\mathbb C$? It could also be $\mathbb Q$. And there are other possibilities. It all depends upon how the problem is stated and also upon its context.